# Error in file reading

Tags: c

When I am reading a file having amounts separated by "\n". The code for it is:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%llu",&amt) == 1)
 {
  fscanf(fp,"%ld",&amt);
  printf("\n %d",i);
  printf("   %ld",amt);
  t_amt=t_amt+amt;
  i++;
 }
```

The problem is if the figure is

99000
100
1000
123
456
12000
6000
780000

then the program prints

```
1 100
2 123
3 12000
4 780000
```

Problems:

1. It is skipping some figure. Kindly help me rectify the error.

Comment: `feof` probably doesn't work like you think it does.

Answer (score 6):

> It is repeating the last figure. Kindly help me rectify the error.

[`feof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) is not set until an attempt is made to read beyond the end of the file. When the last value is read the next call to [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) fails leaving `amt` unchanged. Check the result of `fscanf()` immediately:

```
/* Returns number of assignments made. */
while(fscanf(fp," %llu",&amt) == 1)
{
}
```

> Moreover I am declaring amt as unsigned long long to store a positive value. which can range from 1 to 9999999. Please tell me which kind of value or data type to be used for this purpose.

To determine the ranges of the integer types see the macros `INT_MAX/INT_MAX`, `LONG_MIN/LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN/LLONG_MAX`, `UINT_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX` and `ULLONG_MAX` defined in header [limits.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) but `long` is guaranteed by the standard (from section *5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types*  of the C99 standard) to be sufficient to store the range of values required:

- minimum value for an object of type long int LONG_MIN -2147483647 // -(231-1)
- maximum value for an object of type long int LONG_MAX +2147483647 // 231-1

Comment: The declaration procedure to be used for **LONG_MAX**

Comment: @user2279298, do you mean what type? If so, then `long`.

Comment: **while(fscanf(fp,"%llu",&amt) == 1)** 
It is not working it is **reading some value** and **some values are left**

That is
The file contains
99000
100
1000
123
456
12000
6000
780000

Then the output is 
100
123
12000
780000

Comment: @user2279298, use `" %llu"` to skip whitespace between reads of the integer values: note the leading space.

Answer (score 0):

> problem 2 Moreover I am declaring amt as unsigned long long to store a
>   positive value. which can range from 1 to 9999999. Please tell me
>   which kind of value or data type to be used for this purpose.

If the range of the `amt` is between 0 and 9999999 then you can use `unsigned int` type `"%u"`. it's in the range

And you can even use `int` type `"%d"` it's from -2147483647 to +2147483647

Answer (score 0):

You checked !feof(fp) **before** attempting to read another value, so for the last iteration there is no more data to read but you also have not reached the end of the file - one more attempt to read occurs, fails, and the value of **amt** is unchanged from the previous iteration.

A better loop structure is to incorporate the read command into the condition test, as follows:

```
char line[1000];
while(fgets(line,1000,fp)!=NULL) {
    if(sscanf(line,"%llu",&amt)==1) t_amt=t_amt+amt;
}
```

Be aware that it is better to use fgets and sscanf than fscanf. Why? Because fscanf() will fail to assign a value to **amt** if it encounters a lone "-" or "." , but can still return a "1" indicating a successful read when this happens, presumably because "-" and "." are potentially the first characters in a valid number, even if a number does not follow. The manuals do not appear to mention this!

Comment: If i use this code then it reads first value as 0 and then it reads correct value starting from second it reads it as first value of the file.

**while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
     {
      fscanf(fp,"%llu",&amt);
      printf("\n %d",i);
      printf("   %llu",amt);
      t_amt=t_amt+amt;
      i++;
     }**

Comment: Please don't respond to my suggestion by complaining that a completely different set of code doesn't work! getc() is not the same as fgets(). fscanf() is, like I said, sometimes unreliable. And if you INSIST on using fscanf() after two redundant calls to getc(), obviously the file pointer will have moved beyond the number you are trying to read. Please try the code I posted, first.

Comment: **line[1000]** is reporting error **Size of the type is unknown or zero**

Comment: Should have read "char line[1000]", and should have had a semicolon at the end of the line - now corrected. And obviously you need to include the correct headers and define your other variables, and equally obviously this will not print any output - I'm just trying to show you the basic method of reading numbers from an ASCII file, not give you a ready-made solution :)